# How to get the response body of JSON format when using Jenkins rest api to create job?

Tags: api, rest, jenkins

The .../api/json seems only working for query info with GET method. When I request /createItem?name=xxx or /createItem/api/json?name=xxx with POST method, it always return the response body of HTML。

This is very inconvenient to get error information，for example, when the job already exists,it return like this [image]

Comment: Do you pass a `Accept: application/json` header?

Comment: @Scriptable, I tried, it's not working.